# Using makefile with cgo

Tags: go, makefile, cgo

I am compiling a CGO-enabled Go program using gcc in windows. The gcc comes precompiled into webots.

I can compile successfully the c program alone using the following makefile:

```
### Do not modify: this includes Webots global Makefile.include
null :=
space := $(null) $(null)
WEBOTS_HOME_PATH?=$(subst $(space),\ ,$(strip $(subst \,/,$(WEBOTS_HOME))))
include $(WEBOTS_HOME_PATH)/resources/Makefile.include
gobuild:
    go build -x -v
```

But if I run `make gobuild` it fails with the error: `fatal error: webots/robot.h: No such file or directory`

The header file `webots/robot.h` cannnot be located when building with/for cgo using `make gobuild`, but it is found when building with `make`.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Add the directory containing the webots/robot.h file to the include path when building with make gobuild. You can do this by adding the -I flag followed by the path to the directory containing the header file to the go build command in your makefile. For example:

```
gobuild:
    go build -x -v -I/path/to/webots/include
```